# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory in Opencv face_recognition python

Tags: python, opencv, operating-system

I am trying to make a face_recognition using the face-recognition dlib library, but it gives an error(I am new to python).

```
import os
import face_recognition
import cv2
images=os.listdir('dataset')
img=face_recognition.load_image_file("a.jpg")
(top,right,bottom,left)=face_recognition.face_locations(img)[0]
cv2.rectangle(img,(left,top),(right,bottom),(0,255,0),3)
unknow_encode=face_recognition.face_encodings(img)[0]
for image in images:
    path=os.path.join(image)
    know_image=face_recognition.load_image_file(path)
    know_encode=face_recognition.face_encodings(know_image)[0]

result=face_recognition.compare_faces([know_encode],unknow_encode)
if result[0]==True:
    name=image.split(".")[0]
    print(name)
    cv2.putText(img,name,(left,top+10),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SCRIPT_SIMPLEX,2,(255,0,0),3)
    cv2.imshow("recognize",img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    break
else:
    print("unknow person")
```

**This is my error**

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'a.jpg'
```

It says that there is no such directory as a.jpg in the "dataset" folder, but there is an image. This is the image:
[you can see that the image is there. I dont know why this is happening.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IU9pO.jpg)

Please help. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: What line is this error referring to?

Comment: It will look for `a.jpg` in the same folder as the script you're running as you didn't specify a different path. Are the script and the image in the same folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It says that there is no such directory as a.jpg in the "dataset" folder

No, that is not what the error means.

The code is looking for that file in the *current directory*, not in the dataset folder.

You did call `os.listdir(r'/home/pi/Desktop/dataset/')`, but that does not change the current directory.

Use the full pathname to open the file:

```
img=face_recognition.load_image_file("/home/pi/Desktop/dataset/a.jpg")
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I moved the dataset folder from Desktop to the current directory, but it still gives the same error, I changed the code as you can see in the edited answer. It gives the same error.